# What trees are those?

Tags: identification

It looks like several intertwined trunks, thin and tall, little branching, seven-pointed leaves.

It's a Japanese park, so it's probably Asian.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Other than being green, while most of the ones I've met in the USA are red, looks like Japanese Maple. Which is hardly a specific ID, so, comment, not answer.